# How do I work with Rails 3 cookies and helpers?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, helpermethods

I created a user and stored the id in a permanent cookie:

```
def save_user_id_cookie
  cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = @user_id
end
```

Here is a [link](https://github.com/alexgodin/sleepwiththefish.es/blob/c6b5452c21075d40a41dd74dc0bb1272ac7dbc06/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb#L2).

and then try to access it:

```
helper_method :current_user

private
def current_user
  @current_user = @current_user || User.find(cookies.signed[:user_id])
end
```

Here is a [link](https://github.com/alexgodin/sleepwiththefish.es/blob/c6b5452c21075d40a41dd74dc0bb1272ac7dbc06/app/controllers/application_controller.rb#L8).

I see the cookie on my machine but when I try to load the homepage I get:

```
Couldn't find User without an ID

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8:in `current_user'
```

The controller is [here](https://github.com/alexgodin/sleepwiththefish.es/blob/c6b5452c21075d40a41dd74dc0bb1272ac7dbc06/app/controllers/users_controller.rb#L8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe this line

```
@current_user = @current_user || User.find(cookies.signed[:user_id])
```

should be

```
@current_user = @current_user || User.find(cookies[:user_id])
```

*side note: for little less code you can try assigning like

```
@current_user ||= User.find(cookies[:user_id])
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `save_user_id_cookie`:

```
def save_user_id_cookie
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = @user_id # may be @user.id?
    puts 'saved cookie'
end
```

`@user_id` is nil. I think you should use `@user.id` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@current_user = @current_user || User.find(*cookies.signed[:user_id])
```

Notice the * before the cookies.

and yes, as `@nash` pointed out, that `user_id` should be actually `user.id`.
I didn't bother to look there for errors, as you said that you could see the cookie on your machine.